# Total of Distinc rows on new field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

i want to sum the total of the values of all distinc values of one column of my table into a new 'Div' or 'Text Field' but i cant find myself to do it, i have low knowledge on Javascript and im using jquery datatables for my table build

At the moment this is my javascript code but is not working:

```js
     var dataTable = $('.datatable-column-search-inputs').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
       
  $('#sel0').on('change', function () {
          dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();

    var api = this.api(), data;
     // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
    var intVal = function (i) 
    {
    return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
     };

                   // Total over all pages
    //I want to sum al distinct values of column 3 (this is the column of distinct values)
                   data = api.column('.sum').data();//like data=api.colum('.sum').unique().data();
                   total = data.length ?
                       data.reduce(function (a, b) {
                           return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                       }) :
                       0;

                      $(api.column(3).footer()).html(
                       ( $' + total + ' total)'
                   );

                   });
```

is there a way to sum values of a column for each distinc value of a column?

Comment: Can you update your snippet so it will present the real situation?

Comment: You'll need to define "not working" in a little more detail. And your actual code including the data would be helpful. Doing what you want is really easy to do server-side (and faster), but that might not be an option.